# Why is my format validation failing for permalinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, format, permalinks

I have written an rspec test for checking invalid characters in my permalink:

```
  describe "formatting permalinks when creating a page" do

    it "does not allow crazy characters" do
      page = create(:page, permalink: '#$%^&*first-title')
      expect(page).to have(1).errors_on(:permalink)
    end

  end
```

In my `page.rb` model, I have this validation implemented to make it pass:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :permalink, format: {:with => /\A[a-zA-Z-]+\Z/, :on => :save!}

  before_create :create_slug

  def create_slug
    self.permalink = self.permalink.parameterize
  end
end
```

But I get his error:

```
expected 1 errors on :permalink, got 0
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create_slug calls parameterize. Because it's run as a before_create, it changes '#$%^&*first-title' to "first-title".

Also, [according to the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers), on: should only be used with create and update, so I'm not sure this is running at all.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no need for the validation?

Comment: The test still fails even if I remove the validation. How do I correct this?

Comment: Try removing the :on => :save! part of your validation, or (b) remove the :create_slug before filter

Comment: I did not realize parameterize did so much - I have cancelled the test for now.

Comment: Yeah, parameterize is pretty neat (and/or dangerous)! Take a look at the docs here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize